# Iterate through Nested Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to Iterate through a nested array and having trouble extracting the correct value.

My Json FIle

```
var regions = [
{
    "id": 265592,
    "longName": "Amsterdam 1",
    "name": "ams01",
    "statusId": 2,
    "regions": [
        {
            "description": "AMS01 - Amsterdam",
            "keyname": "AMSTERDAM",
            "sortOrder": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 814994,
    "longName": "Amsterdam 3",
    "name": "ams03",
    "statusId": 2,
    "regions": [
        {
            "description": "AMS03 - Amsterdam",
            "keyname": "AMSTERDAM03",
            "sortOrder": 26
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 1004997,
    "longName": "Chennai 1",
    "name": "che01",
    "statusId": 2,
    "regions": [
        {
            "description": "CHE01 - Chennai ",
            "keyname": "CHENNAI",
            "sortOrder": 30
        }
    ]
},
```

I would like to extract only the Key name from the Regions Array into an Array.

MY code which works fine and gives me the output:

```
const regions3 = []
for (let i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
    const element = regions[i]; 
    const regions1 = (element.regions)
    for (let j = 0; j < regions1.length; j++) {
        const element1 = regions1[j];
        const element2 = element1.keyname;
        regions3.push(element2)
        console.log(regions3)
    }
}
```

Output

```
AMSTERDAM
AMSTERDAM03
CHENNAI
```

I would like to know if there a faster way to iterate rather than running it into two for loops??

Thank you

Comment: Anish, as you can see from the comments on one of the answers below, it is not clear whether the inner `regions` array can contain more than one object. Maybe you could clarify in the question or your example data.

Comment: @MarkMeyer _This_ question _is_ clear. Ask your own question instead of attempting to superimpose your own data structure and requirement into this existing question.

Comment: @MarkMeyer The question as it stands _is_ clear. You are intentionally ignoring the data structure, language used and expected output in the _actual_ question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.map()` and destructuring assignment

```js
var regions = [{"id":265592,"longName":"Amsterdam 1","name":"ams01","statusId":2,"regions":[{"description":"AMS01 - Amsterdam","keyname":"AMSTERDAM","sortOrder":0}]},{"id":814994,"longName":"Amsterdam 3","name":"ams03","statusId":2,"regions":[{"description":"AMS03 - Amsterdam","keyname":"AMSTERDAM03","sortOrder":26}]},{"id":1004997,"longName":"Chennai 1","name":"che01","statusId":2,"regions":[{"description":"CHE01 - Chennai ","keyname":"CHENNAI","sortOrder":30}]}];

let res = regions.map(({regions: [{keyname}]}) => keyname);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188196/discussion-on-answer-by-guest271314-iterate-through-nested-array-in-javascript).

Comment: @guest271314, Thank you, that works well. Would it be possible to just explain on how this is actually working. I tried the map function and understood the Syntax. 

let newArr = oldArr.map((val, index, arr) => {

  // return element to new Array

});
I was also able to display the id and and Longname using the below code.

let newArr = regions.map((val, i, arr) => {
    console.log(val.id);
    console.log(val.longName)
  });

But to be honest here, I'm unable to figure the logic where the region & Keyname is displayed. Could you just through in some light

Comment: @anishanil The target is the property within the array of objects named `"regions"` where the value is an array of objects where the `"keyname"` is the property value that is destructured, which is similar to `regions[0]['regions'][0]['keyname']`, see [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (not supported in IE/Edge) with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const regions = [{"id":265592,"longName":"Amsterdam 1","name":"ams01","statusId":2,"regions":[{"description":"AMS01 - Amsterdam","keyname":"AMSTERDAM","sortOrder":0}]},{"id":814994,"longName":"Amsterdam 3","name":"ams03","statusId":2,"regions":[{"description":"AMS03 - Amsterdam","keyname":"AMSTERDAM03","sortOrder":26}]},{"id":1004997,"longName":"Chennai 1","name":"che01","statusId":2,"regions":[{"description":"CHE01 - Chennai ","keyname":"CHENNAI","sortOrder":30}]}]

const result = regions.flatMap(o =>
  o.regions.map(p => p.keyname)
)

console.log(result)
```

If you can't use `Array.flatMap()` you can use an external `Array.map()` and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the results into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead:

```js
const regions = [{"id":265592,"longName":"Amsterdam 1","name":"ams01","statusId":2,"regions":[{"description":"AMS01 - Amsterdam","keyname":"AMSTERDAM","sortOrder":0}]},{"id":814994,"longName":"Amsterdam 3","name":"ams03","statusId":2,"regions":[{"description":"AMS03 - Amsterdam","keyname":"AMSTERDAM03","sortOrder":26}]},{"id":1004997,"longName":"Chennai 1","name":"che01","statusId":2,"regions":[{"description":"CHE01 - Chennai ","keyname":"CHENNAI","sortOrder":30}]}]

const result = [].concat(...regions.map(o =>
  o.regions.map(p => p.keyname)
))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Fails with error

const result = regions.flatMap(o =>
                       ^

TypeError: regions.flatMap is not a function

Comment: That's because it's not supported by IE/Edge (and other old versions of the other browsers). That's why I've added the 2nd solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution for this is using [Array::reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var regions = [{"id":265592,"longName":"Amsterdam1","name":"ams01","statusId":2,"regions":[{"description":"AMS01-Amsterdam","keyname":"AMSTERDAM","sortOrder":0}]},{"id":814994,"longName":"Amsterdam3","name":"ams03","statusId":2,"regions":[{"description":"AMS03-Amsterdam","keyname":"AMSTERDAM03","sortOrder":26}]},{"id":1004997,"longName":"Chennai1","name":"che01","statusId":2,"regions":[{"description":"CHE01-Chennai","keyname":"CHENNAI","sortOrder":30}]}];

let res = regions.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => (curr.regions.forEach(x => acc.push(x.keyname)), acc),
    []
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well its pretty much the same thing but using a forEach method or array type in javascript can save you some time. here is an example.

```
const regions3 = [];
        regions.forEach(function(region){
            region.regions.forEach(function(subRegion){
                regions3.push(subRegion.keyname);
                console.log(subRegion.keyname);
            })
        });
```

a forEach executes an anonymous function passing each element in array as the argument to the anonymous function